# How to implement single server-multiclient ethernet communication in Qt(referance fortune server-client)?

Tags: qt, qt4

How to implement single server and multiclient communication in qt.Looking to the fortune server example in qt,the port allocated is different at each time i.e I am not able to control the port allocated.how to allocate port for more than one client and different port for each client connection ??

Comment: Why start multiple servers in different ports instead of starting a `QTcpServer` and `waitForNewConnection` and communicate through `nextPendingConnection`?

Comment: @nurettin : I think you misunderstood the question,I want to run single server,if client1 requests a connection,i should allocate port x to it & communicate,simultaneously if client2 requests connection,i should be able to allocate port y to communicate with it.how to do it?

Comment: it seems you misunderstand the concept of servers. A single listener cannot allocate multiple ports. You will need to create multiple QTcpServer instances to do what you are asking for.

Comment: ok,can you please provide me some sample code to achieve what I want.

Comment: I don't think I understood what you want.

Comment: see,I want to run single server to which i want to communicate with two clients at a time,that is,server should be able to handle both the clients simultaneously.

Comment: server should send data to both the clients

Comment: You can do that without multiple ports!

Comment: my question is how to do it? can you provide some sample code??